# Recursive function to move all multiples of an integer to the end of a list

Tags: python, recursion

I was asked to write a recursive function to move all multiples of an integer (k) to the end of the list. This function `move_multi(num_list, k)` takes a list of integers (`num_list`) and an integer (`k`) as parameters and returns `None`.

#### Sample run of the code:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
k = 3
move_multi(nums, k)
print(nums)
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6]
```

#### Rules:

1. A helper function may be used.
2. No loop allowed.
3. The non-multiples and multiples have to be in the original relative order.
4. `move_multi(num_list, k)` must return `None` and *only* has 2 parameters.

I have a problem identifying the base case and thus completely clueless to even start working on the question.

#### My attempt:

```
def move_multi(num_list, k):
    if len(num_list) == 0:                 # base case
       return None
    if num_list[0] % k == 0:               # if [0] is a multiple of k
        num_list.append(num_list.pop(0))
        move_multi(num_list[1:], k)
    else:                                  # if [0] is not a multiple of k
        move_multi(num_list[1:], k)
    return None
```

But after calling the function, the list is still the same as before.

Comment: but this question has to be done in a recursive way. No loop allowed.

Comment: `[nums.pop(i) for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1) if nums[i] % k][::-1] + nums`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the elements within each of the two categories must stay the same, then you can use this algorithm:

Have an index go from left to right through the list. Whenever a value is a multiple of *k*, then pop it out the list and append it to the end. At the same time increase a counter named `done` that keeps track of how many multiples have been moved like that to the end of the list.

When the index reaches the start of the last section of the list (having `done` number of values), then the base case is reached.

As you are allowed to create a helper function, you can provide such helper function with the two indexes as arguments; the recursion happens in the nested, helper function:

```
def move_multi(nums, k):
    def recur(i, done):
        if i + done >= len(nums):
            return
        if nums[i] % k == 0:
            nums.append(nums.pop(i))
            recur(i, done+1)
        else:
            recur(i+1, done)
    recur(0, 0)

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
k = 3
move_multi(nums, k)
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6]
```

#### Your attempt

The attempt that you added to your question fails because it uses slicing when passing a list to the recursive call:

```
num_list[1:]
```

But then you have no way to get the result back: any mutation through `append` and `pop` will now happen on a copy of `num_list` of which you have no reference once the function returns. You should pass the list itself, and not a sliced copy of it, and pass an additional index.

## Minimising the number of moves

To minimise the number of movements in the list, I would have preferred the algorithm below, which however does not maintain the original order of the values within each of the two categories, but it has a better time complexity in the worst case:

Have two indexes in the list move from both ends to the list towards each other. Only move an index if the value it referenced was at the correct side of the list (based on whether it divides by *k*). If neither of these two indexes can move, swap their values, and then move both of them. When the two indexes cross (= base case) the goal is achieved.

In a recursive fashion this can be as follows:

```
def move_multi(nums, k, i=0, j=-1):  # Two extra arguments with default values
    if i - j >= len(nums):  # NB: j is always negative
        return  # all values have been inspected
    if nums[j] % k == 0:
        move_multi(nums, k, i, j-1)
    elif nums[i] % k > 0:
        move_multi(nums, k, i+1, j)
    else:
        nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]  # swap
        move_multi(nums, k, i+1, j-1)
    

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
k = 3
move_multi(nums, k)
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3]
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but as far as I remember combination of `append()` and `pop()` will cause memory relocation while your first swap option won't. Probably `nums[i], nums[-1] = nums[-1], nums[i]` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, Indeed and that is why I wrote about the swap-based solution (see second half of my answer) that *"it has a better time complexity in the worst case"*. But this is not compatible with the requirement to keep the values in their original relative order (when they belong to the same category).

Answer (score 1):

To be frank with you, I find this exercise a kind of abuse of recursion. You could slice the the array into the first element and the remaining n-1 elements. You then apply recursively the function to the remaining n-1 elements. you have now n-1 elements with the multiples at the end. The first element can either be appended at the start or appended at the end if it's a multiple.

You could split the list into two, recursively call the function on both sublists then merge the two lists by first taking the non multiple elements from both lists and appending them to a new list, then take the multiple elements from both sublists and appending them at the end of the resultant list. Pointless and inefficient, but meets the requirements.

The following is another approach that switches elements:

```
def move_multi(l, n, idx=0):
    if idx == len(l)-1:
        if l[idx] % n == 0:
            return idx - 1
        else:
            return idx;
    else:
        last_non_div = move_multi(l, n, idx+1)
        if l[idx] % n == 0:
            l[idx], l[last_non_div] = l[last_non_div], l[idx]
            return last_non_div - 1
        else:
            return last_non_div
        
n = 2        
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
move_multi(l, n)
print(l)

n = 3
move_multi(l, n)
print(l)

l = [2] * 10
move_multi(l, n)
print(l)

l = [1] * 10
move_multi(l, n)
print(l)

n = 2
l = [2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4]
move_multi(l, n)
print(l)
```

Comment: Actually, there's simpler method - iterate source list and pop item from list if it matches condition, then append rest of the list to result.

Comment: @OlvinRogh The OP wants a recursive solution to satisfy his instructor.

Comment: @OlvinRoght what would be the base case? Do I need more than 1 function?

Comment: @OlvinRogh Ah, ok, I think I understand what you mean. You may agree that the whole exercise is a poor use case of recursion.

Comment: @dorothy the base case is an empty list.

Comment: @Tarik, yes, it's definitely wrong application of recursion

Comment: @Tarik thank you for your answer. hope I am not asking too much. Mind if you can show me some pesudo-code (or even actual code)? I think I understand the logic but not sure how to implement it. Thank you!

Comment: @dorothy, try to give it a shot first. Update your answer even with broken code. I and others will certainly be happy to help you. I will not make you a favor by doing it for you. I want you to learn and benefit. I also suggest you look for good examples of recursion to implement without looking at the solution and solve them until you are comfortable with recursion.

Comment: I have wrote some codes it doesn't work completely but I think I am close to the actual answer. How can I show the code in the comment section?

Comment: @dorothya, just [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67418637/edit) your question including code you've written.

Comment: I have added my attempt to the question

Comment: Provided sample code with a different approach. The first answer by @OlvinRoght implements the first solution I described verbally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next method:

```py
def move_multi(nums, k, idx=0):
    if idx >= len(nums):
        return nums
    if nums[idx] % k:
        return [nums.pop(idx)] + move_multi(nums, k, idx)
    else:
        return move_multi(nums, k, idx + 1)
```

This returns new list which doesn't fully meet your requirements but I've decided to leave it like it is. It's possible to patch it to rewrite source list by using this function as inner function and `nums[:] = move_multi_inner(nums, k)`.

*...* which will look like this:

```py
def move_multi(nums, k):
    def move_multi_inner(nums, k, idx=0):
        if idx >= len(nums):
            return nums
        if nums[idx] % k:
            return [nums.pop(idx)] + move_multi_inner(nums, k, idx)
        else:
            return move_multi_inner(nums, k, idx + 1)
    
    nums[:] = move_multi_inner(nums, k)

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
move_multi(nums, 3)
```

Comment: this function returns None and only has 2 parameters.

Comment: @dorothya, it has 3 parameters, but you can omit third while calling it `move_multi(nums, k)`. Regarding *retuns `None`*, I've added some notes to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the implementation, +1.

Answer (score 0):

This one's also working fine, except it is non-recursive.

```
def multiplier(l1, r):
    l2 = []
    for i in range(0, r):
        if l1[i] % 10 == 0:
            l2.append(l1[i])
    for j in l2:
        if j in l1:
            l1.remove(j)
            l1.append(j)
    return l1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).